# How do I get the HTML in an element using Capybara?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I’m writing a cucumber test where I want to get the HTML in an element.

For example:

```ruby
within 'table' do
  # this works
  find('//tr[2]//td[7]').text.should == "these are the comments" 

  # I want something like this (there is no "html" method)
  find('//tr[2]//td[7]').html.should == "these are the &lt;b&gt;comments&lt;/b&gt;" 
end
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 76):

You can call HTML DOM `innerHTML` Property:

```
find('//tr[2]//td[7]')['innerHTML']
```

Should work for any browser or driver.
You can check all available properties on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)

Comment: Works with `poltergeist` too.

Answer (score 27):

This post is old, but I think I found a way if you still need this.

To access the Nokogiri node from the Capybara element (using Capybara 1.0.0beta1, Nokogiri 1.4.4) try this:

```ruby
elem = find('//tr[2]//td[10]')
node = elem.native
#This will give you a Nokogiri XML element

node.children[1].attributes["href"].value.should == "these are the &lt;b&gt;comments&lt;/b&gt;"
```

The last part may vary for you, but you should be able to find the HTML somewhere in that node variable

Comment: Using Selenium, this answer didn't work for me but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15439366/199712) did.

Answer (score 20):

In my environment, find returns a Capybara::Element - that responds to the :native method as Eric Hu mentioned above, which returns a Selenium::WebDriver::Element (for me). Then :text gets the contents, so it could be as simple as:

```ruby
results = find(:xpath, "//td[@id='#{cell_id}']")
contents = results.native.text
```

if you're looking for the contents of a table cell. There's no content, inner_html, inner_text, or node methods on a Capybara::Element. Assuming people aren't just making things up, perhaps you get something different back from find depending on what else you have loaded with Capybara.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you can do `(node).native.inner_html` to get the HTML content, for example with HTML like this:

```
<div><strong>Some</strong> HTML</div>
```

You could do the following:

```
find('div').native.inner_html
=> '<strong>Some</strong> HTML'
```

Comment: Not for everyone `undefined method inner_html for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Node:0x007ff9aa8c59a0>`

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue as Cyril Duchon-Doris, and per https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/629 the way to access the HTML of an *Capybara::Poltergeist::Node* is via the **outerHTML** property, e.g.:

```
find('//tr[2]//td[7]')['outerHTML']
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the other answers work only in Racktest (as they use Racktest-specific features).

If your driver supports javascript evaluation (like Selenium) you can use `innerHTML` :

```
html = page.evaluate_script("document.getElementById('my_id').innerHTML")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Poltergeist driver, these methods will allow you to inspect what matches:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/poltergeist/1.5.1/Capybara/Poltergeist/Node

For example:

```
page.find('[name="form-field"]').native.value == 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

try calling `find('//tr[2]//td[10]').node` on it to get at the actual nokogiri object

Answer (score 0):

Well, Capybara uses Nokogiri to parse, so this page might be appropriate:

http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html

I believe `content` is the method you are looking for.

Comment: There is no comment method... tried to do this: `find('//tr[2]//td[10]').content`

Comment: Can you post your actual step? It would be helpful to see what you are doing here. I've done page.find(...) and referred to the Nokogiri documentation to parse the response. Maybe I was just lucky... Note that I said page.find. I think Capybara provides the page object where Webrat provided the response object.

Comment: The contents of the step are in the original post.

Comment: `inner_html()` should give you everything within a given node. `inner_text()` should give you all the text inside the node.

Answer (score 0):

You could also switch to [capybara-ui](https://github.com/mojotech/capybara-ui) and do the following:

```
# define your widget, in this case in your role
class User < Capybara::UI::Role
  widget :seventh_cell, [:xpath, '//tr[2]//td[7]']
end

# then in your tests
role = User.new

expect(role.widget(:seventh_cell).html).to eq(<h1>My html</h1>)
```