# Test if text does not contain any HTML

Tags: capybara

I want to test whether some content does not contain any HTML. What is a simple and clean way to do so?

```
page.find(".description").should_not have_content /\<.*\>/
```

Does not work properly, since it fails on `&lt;strong&gt;Lorem` but passes on `<strong>Lorem`. Probably due to the way capybara helps its user with escaping HTML.

Solving with xpaths works, but leaves me wondering if there is not a much simpler solution.

```
page.should_not have_selector(:xpath, "//div[@class="description"]/*")
```

Is there a built-in way to detect wether some text has been stripped of HTML in Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara's `has_content?` (and thus `have_content`) method aims to inspect text rendered to the user, not text in html source of an element as you expect.

Thus, I think Capybara's behavior is correct:

- If html source of `.description` is `&lt;strong&gt;Lorem`, user sees `<strong>Lorem`. Capybara searches this text for `/\<.*\>/` and finds it.
- If html source of `.description` is `<strong>Lorem`, user sees `Lorem`. Capybara searches this text for `/\<.*\>/` and doesn't find it.

If you want to inspect source html of an element, you [can use javascript's function `innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459797/841064):

```
source_text = page.evaluate_script("document.querySelector('.description').innerHTML")
source_text.should_not =~ /\<.*\>/
```

Comment: That requires me to run these steps through Selenium, which is a lot slower and more complex (I already test some Js-interaction, but as little as possible). I think the `has_selector` route is preferrable, then: `page.should_not have_selector(".description strong")`

Comment: @berkes I didn't know which driver you use. Look at other answers in linked question. They are for RackTest