# View HTML of plain capybara element without using the driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

*Please note the difference between my question and others like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071937/how-do-i-get-the-html-in-an-element-using-capybara) is that I am looking for a way to do this without using driver methods.*

Is there a way to view all the HTML of a given Capybara Element without driver support?

Currently, a plain Capybara element allows you to access the attributes, if you know about them:

```
# <span class="one" id="two" data="three">
el = find(".klass")
el['class'] #=> "one"
el['id'] #=> "two"
```

It seems like surely there should be a way to just view the entire set of attributes, but I can't find a way without driver support. Is there a way to get something like this?

```
el.html #=> <span class=\"one\" id=\"two\" data=\"three\">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Here are [the methods you get](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element). The closest you get is [the native method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#native-instance_method), which you do not wish to use. You can see how it is done by drivers by looking at [their code](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Selenium/Driver#html-instance_method) - you need the driver. You can verify this yourself by running `my_cabybara_element.methods.sort`, there just isn't anything there for this.